# HTML5 Gamepad API not working

Tags: html, gamepad, gamepad-api

I'm trying to build an application using the HTML5 Gamepad API but my browser (Chrome 24) seems to totally ignore the gamepads. According to many articles on the web, it should work since Chrome 21

I think it's a material problem because it's not even working on the HTML5Rocks demo page : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/doodles/gamepad/gamepad-tester/tester.html

[image]

I tested with 2 devices : A standard PS3 controller and a Guitar Hero wireless PC controller.

I'm running with Chrome 24 (the API should be working since Chrome 21 according to many articles on the web)

I tried to toggle randomly many options in chrome://flags, without success. I tried almost everything possible.

Is there any known bug or manipulation that should be done in order to make that API working ?

Thanks for your help,
jmpp

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be good PS3 controller support. The easiest way to work around this is to make your PS3 controller emulate a Xbox360 controller.

I have been using MotionInJoy to make my controller work.